# Move element below image using css

Tags: html, css

I have the following layout:

[image]
**Problem:** Because the elements float left the H2 element(show in red) doesn't stay below the image element when the text above the h2 element is too short.

**What I want to achieve**: I would like to keep the H2 always below the image but with the following caveat: I can only use CSS to achieve this (no JS, no new HTML(CSS pseudo elements are a possibility )).

I haven't still got any solution. Can someone help me on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
h2 {
  clear: left;
}
```

A quick little demo for you: http://jsbin.com/xoridiva/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 1):

Just make a div with a `clear:both;` CSS after the img div